# Using saxon:line-number() with the Ant XSLT task

Tags: xslt, ant, saxon

I am using the **saxonb9-1-0-8j** processor.

I am running my transformation using the `<xslt>` task in Ant.

I would like to use Saxon's extension functions such as `saxon:line-number()`.

I have found that the `-I` option allows line numbering for the current document ([reference](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.2/extensions.html#linenumber)).

My question is: How to allow line numbering via the `<xslt>` task?

The [Ant documentation for `<xslt>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) says there should be a nested `attribute` element to pass processor specific settings. However, I wasn't able to find the correct syntax.

How can I use Saxon extension functions like `saxon:line-number()` with Ant?

Comment: You misread the 6.5.2 documentation (poor choice of font): it is `-l` (lower case ell) not `-I` (upper case i)

Comment: @Michael

Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl">
  <attribute name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/linenumbering" value="true"/>
</factory>
```

The suggestion is based on the 9.5 documentation http://saxonica.com/documentation9.5/using-xsl/xsltfromant.html, I would guess it is not different in 9.1, check its documentation yourself at http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ if needed.

Comment: The current list of feature names can be found here: http://saxonica.com/documentation/#!configuration/config-features